# 3D Graphics in Android

Tags: android, graphics, 3d

I want to have a part of my app run a 3d graphic simulation (of simple boxes). Of course I could build this in Unity, but I would rather not have to build the entire app in Unity just for this one part. Is there a way that I could have a Unity module? Like a little widget inside my app that runs a 3d sim? It doesn't have to be Unity.

Comment: 3d graphic simulation (of simple boxes) -> I think opengl is better suited for this